Searchkit webpage encountered an unexpected error after CiviCrm upgrade
I've upgraded my environment
from Drupal 10.2.0 & CiviCRM 5.69.4
to   Drupal 10.2.6 & CiviCRM 5.73.3 (PHP v8.3.7)
But since that upgrade the searchkit (overview) page is broken, however (most of) my reports created in searchkit are still working.
On browse to page https://...../civicrm/admin/search results in = "The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later."
At that moment the plesk logging for this site reports:

2024-05-27 13:03:50    Error   xx.xx.xx.6  500 GET /civicrm/admin/search HTTP/1.0      https://...../civicrm/a?reset=1 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/124.0.0.0   1018    Apache SSL/TLS access


2024-05-27 13:03:52    Warning xx.xx.xx.6      mod_fcgid: stderr: Uncaught PHP Exception TypeError: "Civi\Api4\Service\Spec\RequestSpec::hasValue(): Argument #1 ($key) must be of type string, null given, called in /var/www/vhosts/...../httpdocs/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/Api4/Service/Spec/SpecGatherer.php on line 237" at /var/www/vhosts/./httpdocs/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/Api4/Service/Spec/RequestSpec.php line 179, referer:  https://...../civicrm/a?reset=1             Apache error

I've allready tried to force the searchKit upgrader to re-run by doing: UPDATE civicrm_extension SET schema_version = 1006 WHERE name = 'SearchKit'; Then run cv ext:upgrade-db; doing so updates that value back to 1007, but the report page is still unavailable
Any idea what i did wrong, or how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

That error message is a good start. Looks like something is passing null to RequestSpec::hasValue. Could you please enable the debug and backtrace settings on your site (temporarily) and get the full backtrace for that error? Then I can probably track it down.
